# How can I make this "while" work?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm reading "Programming Principles And Practice Using C Plus Plus", by Bjarne Stroustrup, and I'm on page 66.

I'm trying some things on my own, and I wrote this on Visual Studio:

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h";

int main()
{
    string first_name = " ";
    string last_name;
    int numbert = 0;
    while (cin >> last_name) {
        ++numbert;
        if (last_name > first_name)
            cout << first_name << ": plays guitar!\n" << last_name << " : plays bass!\n";
        }
}
```

What I want it to do is: when I write "Lennon Mccartney" at the prompt, to return:

```
Lennon: plays guitar!
Mccartney: plays bass!
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
 :plays guitar!
Lennon: plays bass!
 :plays guitar!
Mccartney: plays bass!
```

And we all know Mccartney plays the bass. Why am I getting this? How can I fix it, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: [hint] Do you ever change `string first_name = " ";`?

Comment: You probably don't want a loop, just two input statements.

Comment: I think the book will get into debuggers. I will take a look, then. For now, I'm exploring what it is giving me. Thank you, Nathan. Now, about your hint, are you saying it was only reading the input of last_name, and keeping first_name as it's initial value " "?

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting input for first_name you should use below code

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string first_name = " ";
        string last_name;
        int numbert = 0;
        while (cin >> first_name >>last_name) {
            ++numbert;
            if (last_name > first_name)
                cout << first_name << ": plays guitar!\n" << last_name << " : plays bass!\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, man ! That fits in with what I'm learning.

Comment: Please close this question